# How do I make a firestore query to be used with both get() and valueChanges()?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, querying

I am using Angular 8 and have a form where a user can choose what he wants to query the database for and then click either of two buttons - one to view data in realtime on the website, and the other to download the data.

I thought I could make use of *one* function to make a query and then call different functions depending on what button the user clicked, using `get()` for the download and `valueChanges()` for the realtime data view. But when I try this, I get the following errors in the browser console. (This is with `query` as type `any` - if I specify the type as AngularFirestoreCollection I get errors regarding my type for the `get()` part in VSCode)

> ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.query.get is not
>   a function

I can add that I previously had two completely separate (working) functions for downloading and viewing in realtime. And for downloading I used the below query. I gather this is actually a Firestore Query, whereas the "query" I'm trying to use in my updated code is an AngularFirestoreCollection. But is there a way I can make some kind of Query/Collection that will work for both `get()` and `valueChanges()`?

**Old (working) query:**

```
var query = this.afs.collection(collection).ref.where('module', 'in', array_part);
```

**Trying a common function makeQuery():**

```
  onSubmit(value, buttonType): void {
    if (buttonType=='realtime') {
      this.getRealTimeData(value);
    }
    if (buttonType=='download') {
      this.downloadCsv(value);
    }
  }

  async downloadCsv(value) {
    this.query = this.makeQuery(value);
    this.dataForDownload = await this.getDataForDownload();
    this.dataForDownload = JSON.stringify(this.dataForDownload['data']);
    console.log('Data: ', this.dataForDownload);
    var date = new Date();
    var date_str = this.datePipe.transform(date, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH-mm');
    this.makeFileService.downloadFile(this.dataForDownload, 'OPdata-' + date_str);
  }

  getDataForDownload() {
    return this.query.get()
      .then(function (querySnapshot) {
        var jsonStr = '{"data":[]}';
        var dataObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr); //making object we can push to
        querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
          JSON.stringify(doc.data()), ', id: ', doc.id);
          dataObj['data'].push(doc.data());
        });
        return dataObj;
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
      });
  }

  async getRealTimeData(value) {
    this.query = await this.makeQuery(value);
    this.data = this.query.valueChanges();
  }

  async makeQuery(value) {
    var collection: string;
    return this.query = this.afs.collection<DataItem>('CollectionName', ref => ref.where('datetime', '>=', '2020-01-15T09:51:00.000Z').orderBy('datetime', 'desc').limit(100));
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`valueChanges()`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md#valuechanges) is a method used in angularfire to retrieve data from firestore, while the `get()` method is used to retrieve from firestore but using the vanilla javascript.

Mixing both methods will return an error as you have seen in your code. Therefore, since angularfire was created above the javascript firebase code, then you should be able to use `valueChanges()` to view data in realtime on the website, and to  download the data.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this! I was thinking that the `get` method was for the use case when getting data once and `valueChanges` for viewing in realtime. But I guess using `valueChanges` with pipe and `take(1)` perhaps is just as good?

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to get data for download with valueChanges()? When I used `get()`, I made a JSON formatted string that was downloadable, but I'm not getting it to work with valueChanges(). Don't get any history, just things that have changed...

Comment: @Ingrid Please ask a different question with what you got with `get()` and what you are expecting to get with `valueChanges()`. Also there are other methods like `snapshotChanges()` that will give you metadata i think that's what you want

Comment: Well, it's basically the same question, but maybe a bit clearer what I want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61340822/how-to-use-valuechanges-instead-of-get-to-download-data-with-json-string